# convert ant script into gradle script

Tags: ant, gradle

How do you convert ant script into gradle script?
Hi, 
Can you please help me to convert ant script into gradle script. I am new user of gradle.

```
<property name="pm-dir"                value="${PM-DIR}/${BUILD_NUM}" />
<property name="leis-dir"              value="${LEIS_DIR}/${BUILD_NUM}" />

<property name="proxy-name"             value="${PROXY_JAR_NAME}"/>
<property name="proxy-client-name"      value="${PROXY_CLIENT_JAR_NAME}"/>

<property environment="env"/>
<property name="java-home"              value="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>

  <condition property="build-pm">
    <equals arg1="True" arg2="${BUILD_PM}" />
</condition>

<condition property="build-LEIS">
    <equals arg1="True" arg2="${BUILD_LEIS}" />
</condition>


<target name="build-LEIS-components" if="build-LEIS">

    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="clean"
         dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS"
         inheritAll="false"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="ejbdoclet"
         dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS/BusinessServices"
         inheritAll="false"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="jar"
         dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS"
         inheritAll="false"/>

    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="clean"
         dir="${leis-dir}/ETS/trunk/Entitlements"
         inheritAll="false"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="build"
         dir="${leis-dir}/ETS/trunk/Entitlements"
         inheritAll="false"/>

    <mkdir dir="${leis-dir}/JARS/APP-INF/lib/"/>

    <jar jarfile="${leis-dir}/JARS/APP-INF/lib/LEISConfig.jar">
        <fileset dir="LEIS/" includes="datetime.properties"/>
        <fileset dir="LEIS/" includes="log4j.properties"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>


<!--========================================================================
Builds pm using the supplied RE build files, modified by us.
========================================================================-->
<target name="build-pm" if="build-pm">




    <!-- SPPResourceBundle Overrides -->
    <mkdir dir="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/propertyoverrides"/>
    <copy todir="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/propertyoverrides" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="olwpmconfig/propertyoverrides"/>
    </copy>

    <!-- copy build.properties into pm dir, complete with kodo key -->
    <copy file="olwpmconfig/build.properties"      todir="${pm-dir}/pm2/"            overwrite="true">
        <filterchain>         
               <replacetokens>
                   <token key="LOGGINGFLOOR" value="${PERFORMANCE_LOGGING_FLOOR}"/>
                   <token key="BEADIR" value="${BEA_HOME}"/>
               </replacetokens>
        </filterchain>
    </copy>

    <!--the actual Retail Express build scripts to create the pm-main.ear-->
    <echo message="Calling pm Build Script"/>
    <ant antfile='${pm-dir}/pm2/build/build.xml'          target='clean-build' inheritAll="false"/>

    <!--delete the extra copy of jdo.dtd-->
    <delete file="jdo.dtd" />

    <fileset id="required-pm-client-libs" dir="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
        <include name="client/*.jar"/>
        <exclude name="*tests.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <!-- Used to populate value of MANIFEST.MF Class-path attribute. Turns our set of "required" libs
     into a nice space separated string to place in the MANIFEST.MF. Property is used in the "dist"
     task's jar command. -->
    <pathconvert property="client-classpath"
                 refid="required-pm-client-libs"
                 pathsep=" "
                 dirsep="/">
        <map from="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/lib/" to=""/>
    </pathconvert>

    <jar update="true" jarfile="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/lib/pm-core.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${client-classpath}"/>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.retailexp.pm.ui.util.SPPClientStartUp"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <!-- Creates a file Marimba/BigFix/WhatEver can use to track the version of pm installed on a machine -->
    <echo message="${pm_MAJOR_VERSION}.${BUILD_NUM}" file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/lib/version.txt" append="false"/>

    <!-- Remove files we place on classpath from ears, Mantis 10624 -->
    <!-- pm -->
    <move file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/pm-main.ear" tofile="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/old-pm-main.ear"/>
    <unzip src="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/old-pm-main.ear" dest="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/">
        <patternset>
            <include name="lib/pm-server-conf.jar"/>
        </patternset>
    </unzip>
    <move file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/pm-server-conf.jar" tofile="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/old-pm-server-conf.jar"/>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/pm-server-conf.jar">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/old-pm-server-conf.jar">
            <exclude name="log4j.properties"/>
            <exclude name="ehcache-transactional.xml"/>
        </zipfileset>
    </zip>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/pm-main.ear">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/old-pm-main.ear">
            <exclude name="lib/pm-server-conf.jar"/>
        </zipfileset>
        <zipfileset dir="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/" includes="pm-server-conf.jar" fullpath="lib/pm-server-conf.jar"/>
    </zip>
    <!-- EDM -->
    <move file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/pm-edm.ear" tofile="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/old-pm-edm.ear"/>
    <unzip src="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/old-pm-edm.ear" dest="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/">
        <patternset>
            <include name="lib/pm-server-conf.jar"/>
        </patternset>
    </unzip>
    <move file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/pm-server-conf.jar" tofile="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/old-pm-server-conf.jar"/>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/pm-server-conf.jar">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/old-pm-server-conf.jar">
            <exclude name="log4j.properties"/>
        </zipfileset>
    </zip>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/pm-edm.ear">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/old-pm-edm.ear">
            <exclude name="lib/pm-server-conf.jar"/>
        </zipfileset>
        <zipfileset dir="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/lib/" includes="pm-server-conf.jar" fullpath="lib/pm-server-conf.jar"/>
    </zip>
</target>

<!--========================================================================
Builds LEIS
========================================================================-->
<target name="build-proxy" if="build-LEIS">

    <!--copy deploy.properties with the proper jar names and locations-->
    <copy file="LEIS/deploy.properties"        todir="${leis-dir}/proxy/config/build/"    overwrite="true">
        <filterchain>
               <replacetokens>
                    <token key="pmCORE"            value="${pm_CORE_NAME}"/>
                    <token key="pmTRANSFER"        value="${pm_TRANSFER_NAME}"/>
                    <token key="PROXYJARNAME"       value="${PROXY_JAR_NAME}"/>
                    <token key="PROXYCLIENTJARNAME" value="${PROXY_CLIENT_JAR_NAME}"/>
                    <token key="PROXYLIBSDIR"       value="${leis-dir}/JARS/"/>
               </replacetokens>
        </filterchain>
    </copy>

     <ant antfile="build.xml" target="clean" dir="${leis-dir}/proxy" inheritAll="false" />
    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="prod-dist" dir="${leis-dir}/proxy" inheritAll="false">
        <property name="build.name" value="${pm_MAJOR_VERSION}.${BUILD_NUM}"/>
    </ant>

     <ear destfile="${ear-name}" appxml="LEIS/application.xml">
        <metainf dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS/conf/EAR/META-INF" includes="weblogic-application.xml"/>
        <fileset dir="${leis-dir}/JARS/"                   includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${leis-dir}/JARS/"                   includes="APP-INF/**" excludes="APP-INF/lib/wlfullclient.jar"/>
    </ear>

    <!-- Place the proxy-client jar in the pm ear-->
    <zip update="true" destfile="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/dist/pm-main.ear">
        <zipfileset dir="${leis-dir}/proxy/dist/" includes="${proxy-client-name}" fullpath="APP-INF/lib/${proxy-client-name}"/>
    </zip>

</target>

<target name="build-cpc">
    <copy file="${pm-dir}/pm2/deploy/lib/${pm_TRANSFER_NAME}" todir="${leis-dir}/cpc-web-app/webapp/lib/cpc"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="build-all-environments" dir="${leis-dir}/cpc-web-app/webapp" inheritAll="false"/>
</target>

<target name="build-all">
    <antcall target="build-LEIS-components"/>
    <antcall target="build-pm"/>
    <antcall target="build-proxy"/>
    <antcall target="build-cpc"/>
</target>    </condition>

<condition property="build-LEIS">
    <equals arg1="True" arg2="${BUILD_LEIS}" />
</condition>


<target name="build-LEIS-components" if="build-LEIS">

    <!--Go through and build the LEIS modules-->
    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="clean"
         dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS"
         inheritAll="false"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="ejbdoclet"
         dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS/BusinessServices"
         inheritAll="false"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="jar"
         dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS"
         inheritAll="false"/>



    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="clean"
         dir="${leis-dir}/ETS/trunk/Entitlements"
         inheritAll="false"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml"
         target="build"
         dir="${leis-dir}/ETS/trunk/Entitlements"
         inheritAll="false"/>


    <mkdir dir="${leis-dir}/JARS/APP-INF/lib/"/>


    <jar jarfile="${leis-dir}/JARS/APP-INF/lib/LEISConfig.jar">
        <fileset dir="LEIS/" includes="datetime.properties"/>
        <fileset dir="LEIS/" includes="log4j.properties"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>


<target name="build-pm" if="build-pm">



    <mkdir dir="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/propertyoverrides"/>
    <copy todir="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/propertyoverrides" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="olwAMPconfig/propertyoverrides"/>
    </copy>

    <ant antfile='${pm-dir}/amp2/build/build.xml'          target='clean-build' inheritAll="false"/>

    <!--delete the extra copy of jdo.dtd-->
    <delete file="jdo.dtd" />

    <fileset id="required-amp-client-libs" dir="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
        <include name="client/*.jar"/>
        <exclude name="*tests.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <!-- Used to populate value of MANIFEST.MF Class-path attribute. Turns our set of "required" libs
     into a nice space separated string to place in the MANIFEST.MF. Property is used in the "dist"
     task's jar command. -->
    <pathconvert property="client-classpath"
                 refid="required-amp-client-libs"
                 pathsep=" "
                 dirsep="/">
        <map from="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/lib/" to=""/>
    </pathconvert>

    <jar update="true" jarfile="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/lib/amp-core.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${client-classpath}"/>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.retailexp.amp.ui.util.SPPClientStartUp"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <!-- Creates a file Marimba/BigFix/WhatEver can use to track the version of AMP installed on a machine -->
    <echo message="${AMP_MAJOR_VERSION}.${BUILD_NUM}" file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/lib/version.txt" append="false"/>

    <!-- Remove files we place on classpath from ears, Mantis 10624 -->
    <!-- AMP -->
    <move file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/amp-main.ear" tofile="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/old-amp-main.ear"/>
    <unzip src="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/old-amp-main.ear" dest="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/">
        <patternset>
            <include name="lib/amp-server-conf.jar"/>
        </patternset>
    </unzip>
    <move file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/amp-server-conf.jar" tofile="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/old-amp-server-conf.jar"/>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/amp-server-conf.jar">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/old-amp-server-conf.jar">
            <exclude name="log4j.properties"/>
            <exclude name="ehcache-transactional.xml"/>
        </zipfileset>
    </zip>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/amp-main.ear">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/old-amp-main.ear">
            <exclude name="lib/amp-server-conf.jar"/>
        </zipfileset>
        <zipfileset dir="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/" includes="amp-server-conf.jar" fullpath="lib/amp-server-conf.jar"/>
    </zip>
    <!-- EDM -->
    <move file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/amp-edm.ear" tofile="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/old-amp-edm.ear"/>
    <unzip src="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/old-amp-edm.ear" dest="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/">
        <patternset>
            <include name="lib/amp-server-conf.jar"/>
        </patternset>
    </unzip>
    <move file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/amp-server-conf.jar" tofile="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/old-amp-server-conf.jar"/>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/amp-server-conf.jar">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/old-amp-server-conf.jar">
            <exclude name="log4j.properties"/>
        </zipfileset>
    </zip>
    <zip file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/amp-edm.ear">
        <zipfileset src="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/old-amp-edm.ear">
            <exclude name="lib/amp-server-conf.jar"/>
        </zipfileset>
        <zipfileset dir="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/lib/" includes="amp-server-conf.jar" fullpath="lib/amp-server-conf.jar"/>
    </zip>
</target>

<!--===============  Builds LEIS   ========================================================================-->
<target name="build-proxy" if="build-LEIS">


    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="clean" dir="${leis-dir}/proxy" inheritAll="false" />
    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="prod-dist" dir="${leis-dir}/proxy" inheritAll="false">
        <property name="build.name" value="${AMP_MAJOR_VERSION}.${BUILD_NUM}"/>
    </ant>

    <!--copy the proxy jar to the LEIS jars library-->
    <copy todir="${leis-dir}/JARS" flatten="true">
        <fileset dir="${leis-dir}/proxy/dist/" >
            <include name="${proxy-name}"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!--create a directory to hold the LEIS ear contents-->
    <property name="ear.dir"            value="${leis-dir}/bin"/>
    <property name="ear-name"           value="${ear.dir}/LEIS_AMP.ear"/>
    <mkdir dir="${ear.dir}"/>

    <!--create the ear from the directories contents-->
    <ear destfile="${ear-name}" appxml="LEIS/application.xml">
        <metainf dir="${leis-dir}/LEIS/conf/EAR/META-INF" includes="weblogic-application.xml"/>
        <fileset dir="${leis-dir}/JARS/"                   includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${leis-dir}/JARS/"                   includes="APP-INF/**" excludes="APP-INF/lib/wlfullclient.jar"/>
    </ear>

    <!-- Place the proxy-client jar in the amp ear-->
    <zip update="true" destfile="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/dist/amp-main.ear">
        <zipfileset dir="${leis-dir}/proxy/dist/" includes="${proxy-client-name}" fullpath="APP-INF/lib/${proxy-client-name}"/>
    </zip>

</target>

<target name="build-cpc">
    <copy file="${pm-dir}/amp2/deploy/lib/${AMP_TRANSFER_NAME}" todir="${leis-dir}/cpc-web-app/webapp/lib/cpc"/>
    <ant antfile="build.xml" target="build-all-environments" dir="${leis-dir}/cpc-web-app/webapp" inheritAll="false"/>
</target>

<!--=========================================    Build AMP and LEIS  --!>

<target name="build-all">
    <antcall target="build-LEIS-components"/>
    <antcall target="build-pm"/>
    <antcall target="build-proxy"/>
    <antcall target="build-cpc"/>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can invoke Ant scripts from Gradle, could you do that instead?

Comment: Why not try it and post when you have a specific problem? Asking someone to do it for you won't get many responses.

Comment: You should read this guide:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html.  It describes the process very well.

Answer (score 26):

Simply use

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

to import you whole ant script and replace the tasks one by one to get started. Later try to refactor your project into the gradle conventions so that your tasks become obsolete.

Comment: This was not the question. It also does not explain how to convert each task one by one.

Comment: @ThomasS. Stackoverflow is not a place where you post an entire script and get people to do the work for you. To get help instead you ask a specific question, i.e., I have x and I tried y and it didn't work, what did I do wrong? This answer gives you a starting point on how you can use gradle and convert tasks one by one, if you then have a specific problem with a task you ask a dedicated question. To get good answers it also helps to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, the initial question would probably be closed as 'too broad'.

Comment: Your answer does not answer that very question: How do you convert ant script into gradle script?

Comment: There is no automated way. Since no two ant-scripts are alike, the answer is you go task by task and convert them manually, by looking up the gradle equivalent and adding that to the gradle script. Depending on what you are building it also would make sense to first read up on gradle conventions and adapt your layout accordingly, since much is done by convention and plugins in gradle.

Answer (score 11):

Ant and Gradle take some fundamentally different approaches to building java projects. Instead of trying to convert your Ant tasks to Gradle, you're likely to find it easier to use a combination of re-structuring of your project to use Gradle's conventions with some degree of customization.

In your particular case, I would take an incremental approach. Pick 1 of your 9 ant targets (like "build-pm") and focus on building that first. It should give you a good idea of how much effort you'll have to spend converting your ant tasks to gradle.

Comment: Great answer. I think the approaches differences is not highlighted enough when people try to move from Ant to Gradle.. the importBuild answer is everywhere, but what about if I want to get rid of ant and use only gradle? can I rewrite my ant tasks in gradle way?

Comment: However, this answer does not explain how to convert 1 from the 9 ant build scripts to gradle.